# How to enable docker remote API in "Docker for Windows"

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have **Docker Desktop for Windows** 1.12.1-stable(build: 7135) installed on my Windows 10 machine. I want to access docker using the [remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) through port `4243`. I guess this port is not enabled by default. Do you have any idea how to open it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the configuration for docker daemon. 
Add a daemon.json file in the following path: %ProgramData%\docker\config

The file should contain something like this:

```
{
   "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:4243"]
}
```

Then restart docker service.(eg Powershell: Restart-Service docker )

References:

- [How to use Remote API with Windows Container](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fefd317d-5bab-4e34-9289-6fba2695e2cd/how-to-use-remote-api-with-windows-container?forum=windowscontainers)
- [Configuration File reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#windows-configuration-file)

Comment: This seems to have changed. Looking at the second link it states `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json` as the configuration file.

Comment: Keep in mind this is very insecure and opens up connections from any IP Address on the port specified, here's an [updated reference from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/manage_remotehost) for the secure method

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62433679/1374678