# How to change Docker API Port from TCP to UDP

Tags: docker, api

I would like to access the Docker API (running on Windows Server).
Sadly a TCP connection is not possible in our network (at least for this case).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385821/how-to-enable-docker-remote-api-in-docker-for-windows) I found a solution to change the port. But  I am not sure if changing the protocol is possible?

```
{
   "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:4243"]
}
```

Comment: Check out this link: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4635

Comment: Remember that you can pretty easily use the Docker API to completely take over a host: I would not recommend enabling network access to it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option):

> The Docker daemon can listen for [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) requests via three different types of Socket: `unix`, `tcp`, and `fd`.

... `udp` is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time!